# how to grab and ungrab keyboard with a secret password in X11

Tags: c++, x11, xorg

I am programming a C application with X library. I want to disable the keyboard and when the user type a secret password the keyboard will be enabled. Briefly I want to switch between disable and enable keyboard through a secret password.

For example, when the program is running, the user can press keys but it has no effect, when the user type "password" word the program ungrab the keyboard and let the user press keys, but when the user type again "password" word the keyboard will be disabled again.

I have the first part, disable the keyboard and enable it when the user type a password but I can't do the inverse way.

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/Xos.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>


bool isBlock = false;
Display *display;
Screen *screen;
Window window;
char password[6];

void order_password(){
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    password[i] = password[i+1];
  }
  password[6]=0;
}

void handle_event(XEvent event){
  KeySym keysym = XKeycodeToKeysym(display, event.xkey.keycode,0);
  char str[1];
  if (event.type == KeyReleaseMask){
    int len = strlen(password);
    if (len == 6){
      order_password();
    }
    len = strlen(password);
    XLookupString(&event.xkey,str,1,NULL,NULL);
    password[len] = str[0];
    if (strcmp(password, "hello") == 0){
      if (isBlock == false){
        memset(&password, 0, sizeof(password));
        block();
      }else{
        memset(&password, 0, sizeof(password));
        unblock();
      }
    }
  }
}

void block(){
  isBlock = true;
  XGrabKeyboard(display, window,true, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync, CurrentTime);
  XEvent event;
  while (1){
    XNextEvent(display, &event);
    std::cout << "You can't type anything" << std::endl;
    XAllowEvents(display, AsyncKeyboard, CurrentTime);
    XAllowEvents(display, AsyncPointer, CurrentTime);
    handle_event(event);
  }
}

void unblock(){
  isBlock = false;
  XUngrabKeyboard(display, CurrentTime);
  XEvent event;
  while (1){
    XNextEvent(display, &event);
    XSendEvent(display,window,true, 0, &event);
    std::cout << "Now, you can type" << std::endl;
    XAllowEvents(display, AsyncKeyboard, CurrentTime);
    XAllowEvents(display, AsyncPointer, CurrentTime);
    handle_event(event);
  }
}

int main(int argc,char **argv){
  display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
  screen = ScreenOfDisplay(display, 0);

  window = DefaultRootWindow(display);
  isBlock = false;
  if (isBlock == false){
    block();
  }
}
```

So, with this code I start with the keyboard disabled and when user type "hello" word, the keyboard enable again. Now I want to disable it again if the user type the "hello" word.

Note: The password is stored as cirucular list of fixed size (6 in this example). Whe the user type "h", "h" is store in password[0] variable, when the user type "e" the "e" is stored in the password[1] variable. When the size is 6 (for example "Hello w") the next time that user press a key, the first "H" dissapear,if the user press now "o" the content of password variable would be "ello wo"

Comment: C & C++ are not one language - it seems you've chosen C and spammed C++.  C++ tag removed.

Comment: I know it, this example is in C, but the whole program that I am programming is in C++. So for this reason I tagged the question with c++ tag. sorry.

Comment: To avoid this happening, you need a [mcve] that shows the problem in the language(s) you tag.  Strip the non-essential parts of the program and show only what you need to have solved.

Comment: @KevinDTimm The program is not a C program but a C++ one. C++ tag added, C tag removed. There are no `<iostream>` or `<sstream>` or `<fstream>` in C.

Comment: The problem is, as soon as the keyboard is ungrabbed, the program stops receiving keyboard events. Also, this never ending mutual recursion between block, unblock and handle_event isn't going to win you any points.

Comment: well there are a lot more problem here than that.